# Displaying table output from a source function in shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, dataset, shiny

I have written an R macro which converts a dataset into a more legible format. It is complete and has been tested on several datasets so I have now decided to write a GUI to implement this code using Shiny.

My UI code seems to be working.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("DATASET CONVERSION"),

  sidebarLayout(
      fileInput("filein", label = h2("Select a file to convert.")),
      submitButton("Submit")
                 ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("Dataset")
      )
  )
)
```

However the server doesn't seem to be producing any output in the main panel

```
source("Full Code.R")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  input$filein

  output$Dataset <- renderTable({ 
    OUTPUT
  })
})
```

My source code (Full Code.R) has been tested and is fully operational. It requires an inputted dataset called INPUT, and following the code, assigns the converted dataset to the global environment under the name OUTPUT. I cannot reveal the the dataset due to confidentiality reasons, however this is an arbitrary issue in which any dataset could be displayed.

If anybody can spot any mistakes that I've been making, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

As your shiny application is running, shiny needs to update the server part, that's why you'll put your input$filein in a reactive function, which you'll use for your output:

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

```
outputdf <-  reactive({ input$filein   
})    
output$Dataset <- renderTable({ 
  outputdf()
})
```

}

Information on reactivity:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/